Vue js cookies are not stored
If I use the cookies via node js
  const user_token = jwt.sign(user, process.env.SRC_PASSWORD, { expiresIn: "1h" });
res.cookie("token", user_token, {
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: false, // Set this to true if using HTTPS
  sameSite: 'lax'
});

to the user, they are not saved, but if I try to save the cookies directly on a side of the server it works, but that doesn't help me much because in this use case the server is an API.
I just want the cookies I send to localhost8080 to be stored there too.

" they are not saved" - means that you can't access them in vue app in a browser? This prevents it, httpOnly: true
